# Good cryptography/encryption books

Tags: encryption, cryptography

More of a side thing I want to learn since they never really went much over it in college, and yes im sure this has been asked plenty of times but Books/Algorithms get updated. So I wanted to most updated opinions/reviews of it.

I am less concerned about the history of it, but more concerned about actual implementation. And maybe by the end of the book implementing my own pseudo encryption algorithm.

I recall hearing something about Crpytool being a good learning program. I don't know if that is still true or not.

I am guessing typical encryption algorithms can be pretty much implemented in most languages right? Like MD5 in php and c?

Comment: I recommend against using MD5. Go for SHA-2 / SHA-256 at least until NIST Cryptographic Hash Algorithm Competition for SHA-3 is finished.

Comment: It was more for like "learning" Im not actually like needing to encrypt anything right now.

Comment: Ironically, the MD5 in PHP he is referring to is a C function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is [Cryptography for Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1597491047) and [Cryptography in C and C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595025) books which I advise you much

Answer (score 7):

http://www.schneier.com/book-practical.html

And please don't use your pseudo-encryption algorithm for anything more important than your own love letters. It's probably best not to use your own implementations of standard algorithms either.

Comment: I think writing your own implementations can be an excellent way to understand how a particular cipher works. However, using that to explore knowledge is far different from using it to protect information.

Comment: Here's a longer list to pick from: http://www.amazon.com/Bruce-Schneier/e/B000AP7EVS/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1

Comment: the one benefit to using your own algorithms is you know there is no back door. Looks at some of the questions surrounding major products used by millions over the last few years- your data might not be secure from day 1 using someone else's code you don't know and have not audited

Comment: @user1889665 there might be no back door, but unless you are an eminent expert in crypto, there will be an open front door.

Answer (score 2):

The handbook of applied cryptography is worth to read, especially chapter 14.
http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a good [bibliography page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_on_cryptography) on the subject which [history page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Books_on_cryptography&action=history) shows frequent updates.